# Redirect to another component after form submission in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I have the following method to handle form submission-

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 
  axios.get('url').then(response => {
    if(response.data.issuccess){
      this.props.history.push("/SuccessComponent");
    }       
  });
}
```

It changes the URL in addressbar, but UI remains the same.

How to solve this?

Comment: What is `this.props.history`?  Are you using `react-router` perhaps?  What are your route definitions, and are they an ancestor of this component?

Answer (score 0):

This method will not work perfectly.
If you're using react-router-dom package, you need to initially set the route of your successCompoment in the root file mostly app.js.

```
import SuccessComponent from .....link to the file...

<Route path='/SuccessComponent' component={SuccessComponent} exact/>
```

Applying this will work.
If you didn't define the route to a component, you cannot Make a navigate to a URL expecting to render different component not initially defined

Comment: where I need to declare that route?

Comment: In your appjs file, but make sure react-router-dom is installed